# Oracle SQL Developer, how to open table/view by clicking/double clicking on its name in worksheet?

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper, ibexpert

The Oracle SQL developer is what I use these days and it is missing some of my previous tool (IB Expert, great tool by the way) functionalities.

1.How is it posible in SQL Developer to open table/view by click/double click on its name in the worksheet.

2.Clicking on a table/view name under its connection will open the table next to already opened worksheets or SQL files. How could this changed to double click instead?

I am using SQL Developer Version 3.0.04 under Mac OS X 10.6.8.

I have upgraded SQL Developer to the latest(Version 3.1.07) and still have the same issue.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

How to override Single Click to Open tables (or any other object in tree view)
Tools > Preferences > ObjectViewer > Uncheck Open Object on Single Click

Edit:
For version 1.5.5
Tools > Preferences > Database > Advanced Parameter > Uncheck Open object on Single click

Comment: Minor amendment but ... Tools > Preferences > Database > ObjectViewer > Uncheck Open Object on Single Click

Comment: This worked for me

Tools > Preferences > Database > ObjectViewer > Uncheck "Open Object on Single Click"

    OR     This also worked: simply type "Single" in the search box then Uncheck "Open Object on Single Click"

Answer (score 3):

1. Clicking or double-clicking on a table or view name in a worksheet does not open it up.  You can, however, right click on the table name and choose either "Popup Describe" or "Open Declaration".  "Popup Describe" can also be invoked by hitting Shift-F4 (at least on Windows.  Based on the comments, it may be different on Mac OS).
2. I don't believe there is a way to override the behavior of the single click when you Connections tree control.  A single click always opens the declaration of the object.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Popup Describe is working but does not do what I want. By default Shift-F4 is not assigned to any action(in SQLDeveloper under Mac OS) also Popup Describe has no shortcut. Finally the Open Declaration doesn't do anything. This tool needs a lot of improvements.

Comment: Shall I say that Open Declaration, finally, did what I wanted after couple of tries. SQLDeveloper is very flicky.

Comment: @Ali - I don't have any major issues with it but I'm on Windows and using a 1.7 JVM.

Comment: Yes under windows it performs a lot better. I have it installed under windows at home and I don't get as much issues with it.